# RAC role assignment scoped to file share using a for_each

Tags: azure, terraform

I have created a terraform template that creates 3 file shares on a storage account using a **for_each** loop that is working perfectly.

I am trying to assign RBAC role assignments, scoped to each file share using a **for_each** loop, however I keep getting the following error and I am not sure how to achieve this?

**main.tf**

```
###########################
# RESOURCE GROUP CREATION #
###########################
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
    name = var.rg.name
    location = var.rg.location

    # tag is a test to see if I can get them to use a variable map
    tags = "${var.tags}"
}

############################
# STORAGE ACCOUNT CREATION #
############################
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage_account" {
    name = var.storage_account.name
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
    location = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
    account_tier = var.storage_account.account_tier
    account_replication_type = var.storage_account.account_replication_type
    allow_nested_items_to_be_public = false

    azure_files_authentication {
      directory_type = var.storage_account.directory_type
      active_directory {
        storage_sid = var.storage_account.storage_sid
        domain_name = var.storage_account.domain_name
        domain_sid = var.storage_account.domain_sid
        domain_guid = var.storage_account.domain_guid
        forest_name = var.storage_account.forest_name
        netbios_domain_name = var.storage_account.netbios_domain_name
      }
    }
}

########################################
# STORAGE ACCOUNT FILE SHARES CREATION #
########################################
resource "azurerm_storage_share" "file_shares" {
    for_each = var.file_shares
    name = each.value.name
    storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.name
    quota = each.value.quota
}

########################
# RBAC ROLE ASSIGNMENT #
########################
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "rbac" {
    for_each = var.rbac
    scope = azurerm_storage_share.file_shares.*.id
    role_definition_name = each.value.role_definition_name
    principal_id = each.value.principal_id
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
#######################################
# STORAGE ACCOUNT FILE SHARE SETTINGS #
#######################################
variable "file_shares" {
    description = "storage account file share settings"
    default = {
        profiles = {
            name = "profiles"
            quota = "5120"
        }
        o365 = {
            name = "o365"
            quota = "5120"
        }
        msix = {
            name = "msix"
            quota = "5120"
        }
    }
}

#################################
# RBAC ROLE ASSIGNMENT SETTINGS #
#################################
variable "rbac" {
    description = "rbac assignment to storage account, principal id is the object id of the security group listed in Azure AD"
    default = {
        back_office = {
            role_definition_name = "Storage File Data SMB Share Contributor"
            principal_id = "e93a67c7-4bfc-4bbd-a720-b26d9291fa28"
        }
        front_office = {
            role_definition_name = "Storage File Data SMB Share Contributor"
            principal_id = "0280b0c9-295a-4d75-b8d0-a092cf52dabc"
        }
        dev_dev = {
            role_definition_name = "Storage File Data SMB Share Contributor"
            principal_id = "512be349-5444-45b0-80f5-8e59046a0175"
        }
        dev_prod = {
            role_definition_name = "Storage File Data SMB Share Contributor"
            principal_id = "0a676556-cf96-4318-b229-503808da7e1c"
        }
        admins = {
            role_definition_name = "Storage File Data SMB Share Elevated Contributor"
            principal_id = "b0bde374-eb5d-4967-9a4f-cdd41fd7bb23"
        }
    }
}
```

**error**

```
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on storage_account/main.tf line 51, in resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "rbac":
│   51:     scope = azurerm_storage_share.file_shares.*.id
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "id".
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on storage_account/main.tf line 51, in resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "rbac":
│   51:     scope = azurerm_storage_share.file_shares.*.id
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "id".
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on storage_account/main.tf line 51, in resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "rbac":
│   51:     scope = azurerm_storage_share.file_shares.*.id
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "id".
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on storage_account/main.tf line 51, in resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "rbac":
│   51:     scope = azurerm_storage_share.file_shares.*.id
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "id".
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on storage_account/main.tf line 51, in resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "rbac":
│   51:     scope = azurerm_storage_share.file_shares.*.id
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "id".
╵
##[warning]Can't find loc string for key: TerraformPlanFailed
##[error]Error: TerraformPlanFailed 1
```

Comment: What values can `scope` take? A list, a map, a single string value?

Comment: I am unsure to be honest, but the scope is wanting an azure resource ID. If I scoped it to the storage account id it would work without issue, however I'd prefer to scope it to the three file shares as it would make it granular.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [flatten](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/flatten) function. Add the following code to your `locals` :

```
locals {
  rbac_assignment = flatten([
    for rbac_key, rbac in var.rbac : [
      for file_key, file in azurerm_storage_share.file_shares : {
        rbac_key             = rbac_key
        file_key             = file_key
        scope                = azurerm_storage_share.file_shares[file_key].resource_manager_id
        role_definition_name = rbac.role_definition_name
        principal_id         = rbac.principal_id
      }
    ]
  ])
 }
}
```

Then in your `azurerm_role_assignment` resource, use the following `for_each`:

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "rbac" {
  for_each             = { for rbac_assignment in local.rbac_assignment : "${rbac_assignment.rbac_key}.${rbac_assignment.file_key}" => rbac_assignment }
  scope                = each.value.scope
  role_definition_name = each.value.role_definition_name
  principal_id         = each.value.principal_id
}
```

I also changed the attribute reference of the file share, instead of using the id, it must use the `resource_manager_id`.